# drop down menu doesn't show on hover

Tags: html, css

Here is my html for half of my nav, I took some of this from an old project, but I can't get it to work. It's frustrating because this snippet worked for another nav, but I just cant get it to work right.

```css
.ulli {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
 }
  .ulli:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }
 .ulliul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
 }
 .ulliul:hover { 
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<li class="ulli"><a style="text-decoration:none"><font color="FFF">0</a></li>
 <ul class="ulliul">
  <li class="ulliul"><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;"><font color="FFF">1</a></li>
  <li class="ulliul"><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;"><font color="FFF">2</a></li>
  <li class="ulliul"><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;"><font color="FFF">3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: don't use `font` tag it is deprecated. and you are not closing it in your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

For one `<font></font>` is deprecated and you didnt close them anyways so you should just remove them. You need to show the menu when you hover over `.ulli` not the hidden element: `.ulliul`. Also you should change the `class` name of your `li` elements, they should not be the same class as your `ul`:

**HTML**

```
<li class="ulli"><a style="text-decoration:none">0</a></li>
<ul class="ulliul">
    <li class="something"><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;">1</a></li>
    <li class="something"><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;">2</a></li>
    <li class="something"><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.ulli:hover + .ulliul { //need to use '+' because the subnav is a sibling of the element you're hovering over
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L3bcsn58/)

**UPDATE**

Please refer to my comments up above again, you didn't change what I told you to in the HTML:

1. remove all of the `<font color="FFF">` tags from your code, it's not valid, the tags aren't closed, and it's actually stopping your hover from working
2. **change** the class names of your li elements: `<li class="ulli">` to something else, they should not be the same as your `ul`, ex: `<li class="list">`

[**YOUR FIDDLE - WORKING**](http://jsfiddle.net/ta2ckxer/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified your code, find the below HTML,CSS

- Modified HTML structure.
- Removed in-line style.
- Removed  from html and applies style on  tag.
- Styles for multilevel drop-down.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ulli">
    <li>
        <a href="#">0</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="something"><a href="#" >1</a></li>
            <li class="something"><a href="#" >2</a></li>
            <li class="something"><a href="#" >3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li a{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/rs6us5d7/)

Comment: while OP's code obviously needs help, this site is more about explaining why something they are doing is incorrect (for their information and future visitors of this post) not necessarily re-doing it for them and just handing it off to them.

Comment: I have simplified same code. Removed many lines which not required to make drop-down and i explained above code. Hope it's really helps OP to improve coding standard and make best practice.

Comment: im aware, and yes it's obviously an improvement, but again, the question was why it doesnt work, you have explained *what* you have done but nothing about *why* you have done it